# Pass variable to jinja template

Tags: python, templates, jinja2, airflow

I am quite new with Python and jinja and I would need some help about the following problem.

In order to deal with some variable in airflow, I need to define a template which involves a variable `my_variable` inserted by the user. I would need the (integer) value of such variable to be inserted into my template. More precisely, the idea is the following: first, I ask the user to insert a variable

```
my_variable=input('insert the variable:')
```

next, in the case when, for example, the user choose to set `my_variable=2`, I would like to be able to have a template in the form
`my_template="{{My variable is 2}}"`.

Thank you in advance, I hope I managed to explain myself.

Comment: I've never seen DAGs expecting users' input. When and where do you expect users to be asked for input?

Comment: Actually, I just tried to provide a minimum working example. The idea is that I want the DAG to acquire a variable defined in the Variable environment of the airflow UI for example and to pass it into a template, sorry for the misunderstanding. I found some similar issues in other threads but I was not able to find a working answer...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

As per comment the ask is to `acquire a variable defined in the Variable environment of the airflow UI` in such case variables can be references in templated fields using `{{ var.value.my_variable }}` or `{{ var.json.my_variable }}` as per [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html).